# Why does my function return everything except the last item in the array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, frontend

With the code below, I am trying to return all the items in `item.children`. I don't understand why it isn't returning the last item. After logging the results at several places and verifying SQLs, I could finally conclude the part of the code below in a file that is accessed via ajax is creating the array without the last record in the SQL result. I am still unable to find where it is missing the last record to be added to the array `$skus`.

```
        case 'skuLookup':
            $sql = "SELECT i.id, i.sku as parentSku, i.description as parentDescription, sku.item_sku as sku, sku.description FROM sku LEFT JOIN sku_vendor_pivot AS vp ON sku.id = vp.sku_vendor_fk LEFT JOIN sku_internal AS i ON i.id = vp.sku_fk WHERE i.sku LIKE '" . $dbh->escape($call['id']) . "%' AND i.id is not null";
            $sql .= " UNION ";
            $sql .= "SELECT i.id, i.sku as parentSku, i.description as parentDescription, sku.item_sku as sku, sku.description FROM sku LEFT JOIN sku_vendor_pivot AS vp ON sku.id = vp.sku_vendor_fk LEFT JOIN sku_internal AS i ON i.id = vp.sku_fk WHERE sku.item_sku LIKE '" . $dbh->escape($call['id']) . "%' AND i.id is not null";
            if(is_numeric($call['id'])) {
                $sql = "SELECT i.id, i.sku as parentSku, i.description as parentDescription, sku.item_sku as sku, sku.description FROM sku LEFT JOIN sku_vendor_pivot AS vp ON sku.id = vp.sku_vendor_fk LEFT JOIN sku_internal AS i ON i.id = vp.sku_fk WHERE i.id = " . $dbh->escape($call['id']) . " AND i.id is not null";
            }
            $skus = array();
            if($dbh->query($sql)) {
                $parent = null;
                $children = array();
                $count = 0;
                while($dbh->next_record()) {
                    $count++;
                    if($parent == null) {
                        $parent = $dbh->Record['id'];
                    }

                    if($parent != $dbh->Record['id']) {
                        $sku['children'] = $children;
                        $skus[] = $sku;

                        $parent = $dbh->Record['id'];
                        $children = array();
                    }
                    $sku = array(
                            'description' => $dbh->Record['parentDescription'],
                            'value' => $dbh->Record['parentSku'],
                    );
                    $children[] = $dbh->Record['sku'] . " - " . $dbh->Record['description'];
                }
                if($count == 1) {
                    $sku['children'] = $children;
                    $skus[] = $sku;
                }
            }
            $newData['skuLookup']['data'] = $skus;
            error_log("newData['skuLookup']['data'] data:\n" . print_r($newData['skuLookup']['data'], TRUE));
            $data = array_merge($data,$newData);
            break;
```

Comment: It's very hard for us to debug this without the actual context of items inside _buildItems

Comment: Would you like me to share the entire JS file running into 1200 lines of code?

Comment: Or I can print _buildItems and share its contents with you if you prefer this.

Comment: It's bad for archiving purposes but if you must use all 1200 lines of code to produce a minimal example.. try [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or something to help us helping you debug.

Comment: Thanks for introducing CodePen. Please follow the link to see the entire script. https://codepen.io/nbkqmkne-the-encoder/pen/ExmBXOq

Comment: I think the suggestion was to show some of the `items` that are being iterated and passed as params, not masses more code.  Ideally you reduce the code/data to the absolute bare minimum which reproduces the problem - a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - eg with the 2 funcs you've shown here and a small sample set of data.  The smaller and simpler you can demonstrate the problem, the easier for others (and yourself!) to find the problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree that ideally one reduces the code/data to the absolute bare minimum which reproduces the problem. There seems to be a lot that I need to explain for SO to help me  further.

Comment: I could explain the problem better if we can get on the chat so I can give you the access to this application on our staging server to have a look at the page I am currently working on.

Comment: "*I think the suggestion was to show some of the items*" :-) [Here's my attempt at a simplified, minimal running example with dummy data](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/rcz0fwan/).  It runs fine, and does not display the problem you are seeing.  Which means a) the problem is in the actual data, and we need to see a minimum set of it which displays the problem;  Or b) the problem is in the code you've shown here, but not my simplified version (seems unlikely). Or c) the problem is in some other code we can't see.  If b) or c), if you can iteratively add your code until the problem shows up ...

Comment: ... we'll be able to see it to and hopefully someone can help. Though there's a good chance you might solve it yourself by doing that as well! :-)

Comment: Grateful for the time being invested into my issue. I updated the post and see the problem is as you pointed out c) the problem is in some other code we can't see. Please have a look at it now. It is not JavaScript issue anymore, but PHP one.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I hope you are keeping well. I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, the code sets up `$sku` and appends an element to the `$children` array:

```
while($dbh->next_record()) {
    $count++;

    // ...

    $sku = [ ... ];
    $children[] = $dbh->Record['sku'] ...;
}
```

But on the last iteration, those variables are only used if `count == 1`, ie if there was only 1 record at all:

```
if($count == 1) {
    $sku['children'] = $children;
    $skus[] = $sku;
}
```

If I am understanding correctly, it looks like maybe those values are normally used on the next iteration, inside the `if($parent != $dbh->Record['id']) {` test.  But that won't happen for any values set up on the *last* record.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't been able to understand what your answer is. `if($parent != $dbh->Record['id']) {` has already got the those two lines `$sku['children'] = $children;
    $skus[] = $sku;` All I know is that this while loop has got some issue preventing the last element from getting appended to the array.

Comment: I hope to have fixed it. I would like you to have another look at the code to see if you can suggest a new solution that might match mine.

Comment: In fact, the solution I claim to have found is based on what you already suggested. What I did was to have removed `if($count == 1) {` although I am not sure if this is the elegant solution.

Comment: "*`if($parent ....` has already got the those two lines*" - OK, but immediately after that happens, `$sku` and `$children[]` are set again, with new values.  And if this is the last record in the result set, the whole `while($dbh->next_record()) {` loop will not happen again. So those last `$sku` and `$children[]` values you just set are lost.

Comment: Removing the `if($count == 1) {` test looks like it should work, yes ... possibly that test was added specifically for the case when there is only 1 row in the result set, and so exactly the problem we are talking about happens?  There was no subsequent iteration to preserve those freshly set values.